# HTTPS ESP8266WebServerSecure: how to get a client's IP address?

Tags: https, webserver, esp8266

I have a ESP8266 HTTPS server (ESP8266WebServerSecure, core v. 3.0.2).

It works just fine but I cannot get a remote client's IP address the same way as with the plain unsecure ESP8266WebServer. The method `server.client().remoteIP().toString()` just returns "(IP unset)".

Please help to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

It turned to be a bug in the ESP8266 core libraries. See the [fix](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/pull/8693).